# NodeJS - Cannot find module 'spdx-license-ids'

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I am new to nodejs, yeoman and having issue(Cannot find module 'spdx-license-ids') while using an angular generator. I have node, bower, grunt installed. Details below.

Error: Cannot find module 'spdx-license-ids'

```
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bdas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-karma\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\read-pkg-up\node_modules\read-pkg\node_modules\normalize-package-data\node_modules\validate-npm-package-license\node_modules\spdx-correct\index.js:1:80)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using npm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about grunt etc, but to simply install any node library, do:

```
            apt-get install npm
```

from the command line, thereafter any node module should be installed with:

```
            npm install MODULE_NAME
```

e.g.:

```
            npm install spdx-license-ids
```

or to install it globally so node can find it anywhere on your system (not always such a briliiant idea, but anyways), use the global -g flag:

```
           npm install -g MODULE_NAME
```

Those extraneous tools can trip you up sometimes - grunt, yeoman, etc